# Implement Play Asset Delivery In flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How to implement on-demand Play Asset Delivery in flutter through methodchannels.

Actually i am trying to make a dashboard for some app which accesses assets using ContentProvider so i thought play asset delivery might work here.
I know that same can be achieved using deferred components and I have already tried deferred components which is provided by flutter.
You can find it [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components)

Currently, there is an issue with flutter which causes assets to not load when deferred. You can find a link to the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96046).

I do not have any idea of native language and this is the only option I have right now which is implementing a methodchannel so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can achieve the same thing using play asset delivery. You can try a workaround for this
Disable `android:enabled` by default by adding `android:enabled="false"` in your content provider and then use below methodchannel to enable it later

```
package dev.blah.blah;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "dev.dhanraj.kwgt.test.dashboard";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            if (call.method.equals("enable")) {
              ContextWrapper aContext = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
              aContext.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new android.content.ComponentName(aContext, "org.kustom.api.Provider"), android.content.pm.PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 1);
              result.success(null);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        );
          }
  }
```